# How to convert character to ASCII value in ELM

Tags: functional-programming, char, elm

I'm very new to ELM and I would like to ask, how to convert character into its ASCII value (for example 'A' to 65).

Answer (score 4):

As melpomene said you should use toCode. You will have to import it from the Char library. I made a quick example in Ellie:

https://ellie-app.com/7QyfZLsJza1/1

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Char exposing (toCode) -- importing toCode ascii conversion from Char
import Html exposing (Html, text)

main : Html msg
main =
    text (toString (toCode 'A'))
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a solution to this question, could you please post the code in the answer itself instead of behind a link? The link could go bad and the answer would be lost then.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Char#toCode) is confusing (that's because it is confused), but you can use `Char.toCode`:

```
toCode : Char -> Int
```

---

Bug report about documentation: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/837
Fix for documentation: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/c81539f41d2ee85ff0df20a35e61bb94ca3c17a9 and https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/3a6dc880a475aa153d4ac47156dca5f9a9e892c7

Comment: I am using https://ellie-app.com to execute the code and I have received the following error https://prnt.sc/h9fh9t . I am probably doing something wrong so I would like to ask you for a small example

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Elm before. I just looked at the documentation. The last link I posted adds examples to the documentation: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/3a6dc880a475aa153d4ac47156dca5f9a9e892c7/src/Char.elm#L153-L157